# MobileFirst: Adapter Authentication calls Submit success repeatedly in Angular App

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

**Environment:**

- MFPF v7.0
- Eclipse: Luna SR.2 (4.4.2)
- Windows 7

I face an strange issue. I am using `adapter based authentication` in one of my Angular based project.

The app authenticates well, but it **repeatedly** calls the `submitSuccess`.

I guess, it has something with the way Angular works, either I should use Challenge Handler as a Service or Controller. `Because the way MobileFirst detects & handle instances of a/any handler objects. And that cause reference mis-match to dispose off or execute the relevant functions at appropriate time.`

Currently I use it as a service.

Below is the challenge handler that I use.

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){  
    var loginChallengeHandler = angular.module('webApp.loginChallengeHandler', [])
        .service('loginChallengeHandler', function(){

        var _this = this;       

        _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("AdapterAuthRealm");

        _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
            console.error("AuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse:: " , response);

            if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {             
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined' || response.responseJSON.authRequired == true){  
                return true; 

            } else {             
                return false;
            }
        };

        _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){
            console.error("AuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge:: " , response);

            var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

            if (authRequired == true){           
                console.error("------Auth Required----- ");
                _authenticationFailed(response);

            } else if (authRequired == false){           
                console.error("------Auth PASSED ----- ");

                //Now tell WL Authentication that user has been verified successfully so that it finishes the authentication process             
                _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
                console.error("------ submitSuccess ----- ");           

            }   
        };

        _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.userLogin = function(dataObjRef) {
            var loginStatePromise = $q.defer();     

            _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(options,{
                 onFailure: function (error) {                   
                    loginStatePromise.resolve({ state:false , val: "" });
                    console.log("submitAdapterAuthentication Failed called ", error);
                 },          
                 onSuccess: function(response) {                
                    console.log("-> submitAdapterAuthentication onSuccess called " , response);             
                    loginStatePromise.resolve({ state: _state , val: _msg });

                 },
                 timeout: 30000          
            });

            return loginStatePromise.promise;
        };

        _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.logout = function (){

            var userLogoutPromise = $q.defer();

            WL.Client.logout("AdapterAuthRealm",{                       
                    onSuccess: function(){
                        console.log("onSuccess");                     
                        userLogoutPromise.resolve(true);                     
                    },
                    onFailure: function(){ 
                        console.log("onFailure");
                        userLogoutPromise.resolve(false);                    
                    },
                    timeout: 30000
            });              

            return userLogoutPromise.promise;
        };



        var _authenticationFailed = function(response){
            console.error("_authenticationFailed:: " , response);       
            //register failure request
            _this.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitFailure();             
        };

    });
    return loginChallengeHandler;
});
```

I have also tried to bind the handler object with `window` object, so that it can access the handler's instance methods correctly.

*Like:*

```
window.AuthRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("AdapterAuthRealm");

window.AuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
.
.
```

But still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue and here is my solution for anyone facing similar issue in future.

**Solution Description (few words)**

As per my understanding, the IBM MobileFirst is expecting **only one challenge-handler instance** (the object that is create via `createChallengeHandler` function) to *exists* in the app. So most probably it assumes that the instance would be *hooked* into the **window** object.

Now based on this knowledge, we can see that above code is not working even we made instance through service ( i.e. singleton per angular app). Why ? Because, now the handler object becomes *accessible* via *another reference*, and this caused issues in *resolving* the handler references within the WL APIs.

So I just changed a bit of code (`hooked it into window`) so that WL APIs could reach the correct handler instance and *clean-up the requests poll* before marking the call successful and dispose off all the *cached requests*.

One more thing I would suggest.

- Create only `one handler instance` in your client code
- Create it as a `service or factory` - both are singletons in angularjs
- `Avoid using controllers`, because there can be many controller instances within the angular app and it would lead to multiple handler references

And importantly trust IBM MobileFirst :)

**Working Challenge Handler as Service**

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){  
    'use strict';
    var loginChallengeHandler = angular.module('webApp.loginChallengeHandler', [])
        .service('loginChallengeHandler', function(){

    //NOTE:- Below Must be bind with Window Object, otherwise will NOT work as per challenge handlers default behavior  
    window.AuthRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("AdapterAuthRealm");

    AuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {

        if (response && response.responseJSON && typeof (response.responseJSON.authStatus) === "string"){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }        
    };

     AuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){

        var authStatus = response.responseJSON.authStatus;

        if (authStatus === "failed"){           
            console.error("------Auth Required----- ");
            _authenticationFailed(response);

        } else if (authStatus === "passed"){
            console.error("------Auth PASSED ----- ");

            //do something here like change page etc.

            //Now tell WL Authentication that user has been verified successfully so that it finishes the authentication process             
            AuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();           
        }        
    };

    AuthRealmChallengeHandler.userLogin = function(dataObjRef) {
        var loginStatePromise = $q.defer();

        AuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(options,{
             onFailure: function (error) {

               loginStatePromise.resolve({ state:false , val: "" });            
             },          
             onSuccess: function(response) {                

                loginStatePromise.resolve({ state: _state , val: _msg });

             },
             timeout: 30000          
        });

        return loginStatePromise.promise;
    };

    AuthRealmChallengeHandler.logout = function (){      
        var userLogoutPromise = $q.defer();

        WL.Client.logout("AdapterAuthRealm",{                       
                onSuccess: function(){
                    //$state.go("home.login");                  
                    userLogoutPromise.resolve(true);                     
                },
                onFailure: function(){      

                    userLogoutPromise.resolve(false);                    
                },
                timeout: 30000
        });

        return userLogoutPromise.promise;
    };

    var _authenticationFailed = function(response){       
         //register failure request
         AuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitFailure();     
    };

    });//end of service

    return loginChallengeHandler;
});
```

**Adapter**

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null; 
    return {
        authStatus: "failed",
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function Login(request){      
    if(request){

        /* IF user credentials are Verified Correctly
        * and user is authenticated then create User Identity 
        * and return success message if it is required by client app.
        */

        userIdentity = {
            userId: "abc",
            displayName: "ABc",
            attributes: {}
        }; 

        WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);      

        WL.Logger.error("Auth Successful:");

        return {
            authStatus: "passed",
            submitResponse: "send a Success message in case is required on client-side"
        };      

    }else{
        return onAuthRequired(null, "send an error message if required on client side"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with adapter based authentication but I was using pure javascript, so no angular. From that I can tell you it's a MobileFirst issue and nothing related to angular.

This might sound contradictory to the documentations but don't call the submitSuccess function, just call your code on successful authentication. It will work fine and authenticate properly.
Also, make sure that you only have the security test set on the specific functions that you use after auth and not on the auth function itself.

Your code seems fine to me but I'm not that good in angular.

Comment: First of all, Its NOT mobilefirst issue. They way Angular create instances and MFP looks for handler instances is having something different. I think you did not understand my point.

Comment: Can you share a sample project anywhere ?